# How to subscribe to all cloudwatch log groups into kinesis stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-kinesis, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Hi friends is there a way to put all log groups to a kensis stream. From the example it looks like you can only specify one cloudwatch group

```
aws logs put-subscription-filter \
    --log-group-name "CloudTrail" \
    --filter-name "RootAccess" \
    --filter-pattern "{$.userIdentity.type = Root}" \
    --destination-arn "arn:aws:kinesis:region:123456789012:stream/RootAccess" \
    --role-arn "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/CWLtoKinesisRole"
```

Is there a way to autodiscover all log groups.

My usecase is = Cloudwatch logs -> Kinesis Stream -> Functionbeat -> (Elasicsearch)

Comment: Have you tried? Just run the command for two different `--log-group-name`.

Comment: Yeah ofcourse but this is not ideal because new lambdas are created often, i was hoping for a way for it to autodiscover all log groups with some wildcard.

Comment: Sadly, there is no build-in mechanism for that. You would have to develop your own solution for that.

Comment: I would recommend that whatever you use to create your Lambdas also (1) creates the log group (before first execution), and (2) attaches the subscription.

Comment: @Parsifal Im using serverless framework